# Como obter o nome da propriedade em um dr.Read()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Como obter o **nome** da **propriedade** em um **dr.Read()**?

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = null;

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    var record = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        for(int i =0; i< dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            record[dr[i].Name] = dr[i];
        }
        list.Add(record);
    }

}

return list;
```

Como resolvo esse problema?

```
record[dr[i].Name] = dr[i];
```

Preciso pegar o nome da **propriedade** do **dr.Read()** que contem o **valor**

Comment: Não é feio não sabe a resposta. Feio é negativa e votar para fechar sem dizer como se resolve deixando a pessoa sem solução. Mas...

Answer (score -2):

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> ListAll()
{
    try
    {

        connection.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + this.table;

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, this.connection);

        MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {               
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var record = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                {                            
                    record.Add(dr.GetName(i), dr.GetString(i));
                }

                list.Add(record);

            }

        }

        return list;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

e a chamada:

```
var admins = this.admin.ListAll();

foreach (var admin in admins)
    Console.WriteLine(admin["name"]);
```